# Bootstrap popover - manual show with HTML content - work in jsfiddle but not on my local

Tags: bootstrap-4

Below is the html code that my asp.net page generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doPopoverMenu() {
            $('#popoverMenuBtn').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    return $(".popoverMenu").html();
                }
            });
            $('#popoverMenuBtn').popover('show');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span id="popoverMenuBtn" data-toggle="manualPopover" data-html="true" class="cursor-pointer" onclick="doPopoverMenu(); return false;" title="Available Actions">Popover Menu</span>

    <div class="popoverMenu d-none">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-sm">
                <tr><td>Full Screen</td></tr>
                <tr><td>View Attachment</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Upload Attachment</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Remove Attachment</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the popoverMenuBtn, I get the popover that looks like below:
[image]

As you can see, it shows the correct popover title, but the content is missing.

The Chrome inspect shows why.  The popover-body only contains an empty  element.

I put this exact same code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/fkj4rvp1/5/.  It works correctly.  Any idea what might cause it to work in jsfiddle but not working from my local?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please try changing reference bootstrap.min.css jquery-3.2.1.min.js bootstrap.min.js
and 
try removing popper.js on your header. thanks

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's tooltips require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It is weird.  It works if I replace the table with list group or grid.  Somehow popover just does not like table when running from my local.

Replace below:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-sm">
            <tr><td>Full Screen</td></tr>
            <tr><td>View Attachment</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Upload Attachment</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Remove Attachment</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

With

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Full Screen</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">View Attachment</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Upload Attachment</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Remove Attachment</li>
</ul>
```

and the result looks like below:
[image]